# irb doesn't recognize method

Tags: ruby, rubygems

This is weird, and probably due to me being new to ruby. I have created a gem, it works, all the unit tests work, but when i do the following in irb it can't find the "ingredients" method;

```
1.9.2-p290 :002 > require "tablecloth"
 => true 
1.9.2-p290 :003 > tc = TableCloth.new "1 cup of sugar"
 => #<TableCloth:0x864a728> 
1.9.2-p290 :004 > tc.ingredients
NoMethodError: undefined method `ingredients' for #<TableCloth:0x864a728>
from (irb):4
from /home/mikey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.2-p290 :005 >
```

Entire gem is here;

https://github.com/mikeyhogarth/tablecloth

Obviously this is due to me being new to ruby. It's not actually hindering the development, I just want to know why irb can't seem to register that method in this case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are loading a different, older version of the gem in IRB than you are in your unit tests.  Your unit tests probably test the gem code sitting in your development directory, but when you do `require "tablecloth"` in IRB it would load the gem that has been installed to your system's gem's directory.  If you are using RVM, you can look at the $GEM_HOME environment variable to see what directory that is.

You probably need to run a rake task like `rake install` or something like that to install your gem before you can use it in irb.

Comment: Thanks bud, will try this out!

Comment: You can see what version it is loading with `gem which tablecloth` and if you `gem install gem-open` you can also do `gem open tablecloth` and it will open the gem that gets loaded in your `$EDITOR`, allowing you to browse the gem that actually gets loaded.

Comment: worked a treat man, I had earlier built the gem when i first started. Rebuilding basically fixed it. I guess the part i didn't get was that I thought "reqiure" would reqilre the file specified, din't realise it would check the gems first